# assigning variable in "with" to global variable

Tags: python, graphviz

I'm using the example on [graphviz (cluster.py)](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html)

and when I move these lines out of the **with** the nodes aren't drawn shown below

```
 # cluster.py - http://www.graphviz.org/content/cluster

from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('G', filename='cluster.gv')
b = None   #------------------------------CREATE NEW GLOBAL 

with g.subgraph(name='cluster_0') as c: 
    b = c #-------------------------------ASSIGN TO GLOBAL
    b.attr(style='filled')

b.attr(color='lightgrey') #-----------------MOVE OUTSIDE OF WITH
b.node_attr.update(style='filled', color='white')
b.edges([('a0', 'a1'), ('a1', 'a2'), ('a2', 'a3')])
b.attr(label='process #1')
```

It doesn't work is there a workaround?

Comment: you tried `global b` in the with ?

Comment: yeah but I need it outside the with bc I'm using it elsewhere in my code :/

Comment: `.subgraph` requires the subgraph to be filled in immediately for some reason. But you *can* pass an already-existing `Graph` instance *instead* of using the `with` statement.

Comment: This doesn't matter much, but you don't need the `b = None`. A `with` statement creates a new context, but *not* a new scope.